# Perforce Translation of file content failed near line 1 file

Tags: c++, perforce

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6utohhB.png]

Perforce is refusing to accept my file, I don't know why. I check logs and this is what I get:

```
00004158 11:58:25.751 Helix P4V/NTX64/2020.1/1966006
00004158 11:58:25.752 OS name: Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit
00004158 11:58:25.752 Version: 10.0.19041 Build 19041
00004158 11:58:25.752 System name: DECIL-PC
00004158 11:58:25.752 System manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
00004158 11:58:25.752 System model: MS-7A34
00004158 11:58:25.752 System type: x64
00004158 11:58:25.752 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.752 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.752 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753 Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor            
00004158 11:58:25.753   Processor revision: 101
00004158 11:58:25.753 Total physical memory: 15.96 GB RAM
00004158 11:58:25.753 Available physical memory: 2.25 GB RAM
00004158 11:58:25.753 Total virtual memory: 59.89 GB RAM
00004158 11:58:25.753 Available virtual memory: 24.02 GB RAM
00004158 11:58:25.753 Pagefile space: 43.93 GB RAM
00004158 11:58:25.753 Helix Visual Client version:  P4V/NTX64/2020.1/1966006
00004158 11:58:25.753 Qt build library:  5.12.7
00004158 11:58:25.753 Qt runtime library:  5.12.7
00004158 11:58:27.240 [0x1f7e186ba90] info
00004158 11:58:27.251 [0x1f7eafdea90] protects -m -h 192.168.1.51
00004158 11:58:27.253 [0x1f7eafde760] client -o
00004158 11:58:27.805 [0x1f7e186c150] info
00004158 11:58:27.821 [0x1f7eafdd660] protects -m -h 192.168.1.51
00004158 11:58:27.830 [0x1f7e7c8a780] client -o
00004158 11:58:27.940 [0x1f7eafdea90] spec -o client
00004158 11:58:28.156 [0x1f7eb08cbb0] stream -o //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 11:58:28.156 [0x1f7eb08af00] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 11:58:28.156 [0x1f7eb08a9b0] depots
00004158 11:58:28.157 [0x1f7eb08bde0] protects
00004158 11:58:28.157 [0x1f7eb089580] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 11:58:28.157 [0x1f7eb08b450] spec -o job
00004158 11:58:28.376 [0x1f7eb08aac0] spec -o stream
00004158 11:58:28.377 [0x1f7eb08c440] spec -o depot
00004158 11:58:28.491 [0x1f7eb08ace0] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 11:58:28.491 [0x1f7eb08a570] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 11:58:28.491 [0x1f7eb08caa0] groups -u decil
00004158 11:58:28.491 [0x1f7eb08c660] property -l -n P4
00004158 11:58:28.783 [0x1f7eb08b560] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 11:58:28.788 [0x1f7eb4aca50] spec -o change
00004158 11:58:29.161 [0x1f7eb4a5bd0] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil
00004158 11:58:29.166 [0x1f7eb795aa0] spec -o label
00004158 11:58:29.491 [0x1f7eb792690] change -o
00004158 11:58:29.497 [0x1f7eb1a1400] streams
00004158 11:58:29.497 [0x1f7eb78d5d0] opened -So
00004158 11:58:29.497 [0x1f7eb967b50] login -s
00004158 11:58:29.499 [0x1f7eb967b50][13001d46] User decil ticket expires in 11 hours 43 minutes.
00004158 11:58:29.500 [0x1f7eb78d5d0][21051b92] Client HVS_Game does not have an open stream.
00004158 11:58:29.500 [0x1f7eb9696f0] counter change
00004158 11:58:29.500 [0x1f7eb968b40] repos
00004158 11:58:29.504 [0x1f7eb113c60] fstat -Olhp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.sln c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\README.md c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\p4ignore.txt c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.uproject
00004158 11:58:29.543 [0x1f7eb113c60][21111977] c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.sln - no such file(s).
00004158 11:58:29.551 [0x1f7eb96d160] dirs //depot/* //streamsDepot/* //streamsDepot/mainline/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/Missions/*
00004158 11:58:29.551 [0x1f7eb114440] fstat -Olhp -Dl -F ^headAction=delete & ^headAction=move/delete //depot/* //streamsDepot/* //streamsDepot/mainline/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/Missions/*
00004158 11:58:29.585 [0x1f7eb114440][21111977] //depot/* - no such file(s).
00004158 11:58:29.585 [0x1f7eb114440][21111977] //streamsDepot/* - no such file(s).
00004158 11:58:29.615 [0x1f7ebb27650] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 11:58:29.659 [0x1f7eb114d40] fstat -Olhp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_AttributeSet.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\WeaponSystemConstants.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSServer.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameInstance.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\GA_WeaponFire.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameMode.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_CheatManager.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_CharacterMovementComponent.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameInstance.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_HUD.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_LocalPlayer.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\CaptureNode.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\AbilityTask_WeaponFire.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\GlobalStructs.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_Character.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameState.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_AttributeSet.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\HomeBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HeroDatabase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_CheatManager.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\AbilityTask_WeaponFire.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\ProjectileBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerController.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameState.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\CipherBeacon.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameMode.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_LocalPlayer.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Components\CharacterSoundsComponent.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerController.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\ProjectileBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\HVS.Build.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CaptureNode.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_CharacterMovementComponent.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_HUD.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerState.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameSession.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerState.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\GA_WeaponFire.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\HomeBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\WeaponBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSClient.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_Character.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSEditor.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerStart.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HeroDatabase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameSession.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\WeaponBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerStart.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CipherBeacon.cpp
00004158 11:58:29.707 [0x1f7ebbe9d80] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 11:58:29.726 [0x1f7eb114f80] fstat -Olhp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CaptureNode.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\HomeBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CipherBeacon.cpp
00004158 11:58:31.559 [0x1f7ebba4520] change -o 123
00004158 11:58:31.738 [0x1f7eb113c60] fstat -Olhp -Rco -e 123 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 11:58:31.880 [0x1f7eb1148c0] fstat -m1 -Olhp -Rcu -e 123 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 11:58:31.905 [0x1f7eb1148c0][21111977] //HVS_Game/... - no such file(s).
00004158 11:58:33.110 [0x1f7eba68840] submit --parallel=0 -f submitunchanged -s -i
00004158 11:58:33.146 [0x1f7eba68840][2204040e] Translation of file content failed near line 1 file C:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 11:58:33.146 [0x1f7eba68840][30221c33] Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 123'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
00004158 11:58:34.115 [0x1f7eea814d0] change -o 123
00004158 11:58:34.115 [0x1f7eea816f0] change -o
00004158 11:58:34.120 [0x1f7eea551e0] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 11:58:34.120 [0x1f7eea55620] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil
00004158 11:58:34.153 [0x1f7eb114c20] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 11:58:34.156 [0x1f7eec50680] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 11:58:34.156 [0x1f7eec50240] change -o
00004158 11:59:20.922 [0x1f7eb2a9120] dirs //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/*
00004158 11:59:20.938 [0x1f7eb114c20] fstat -Olhp -Dl -F ^headAction=delete & ^headAction=move/delete //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/*
# 2020/10/24:12:00:47
00004158 12:00:47.654 [0x1f7eec519f0] revert -a //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:00:51.800 [0x1f7eb2a9450] revert -a //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:00:51.835 [0x1f7eec4ff10] revert -n //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:00:51.837 [0x1f7eec4ff10][13001941] //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp#2 - was edit, unlocked and reverted
00004158 12:00:51.952 [0x1f7eb115880] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:00:53.255 [0x1f7eec4fcf0] revert //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:00:53.255 [0x1f7eec4fcf0][13001941] //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp#2 - was edit, unlocked and reverted
00004158 12:00:53.392 [0x1f7eb1149e0] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:01:04.114 [0x1f7ee87c630] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil -c HVS_Game
00004158 12:01:04.131 [0x1f7ee87b750] change -o
00004158 12:01:04.193 [0x1f7eb96d5a0] change -o
00004158 12:01:05.329 [0x1f7eb805ad0] sync -n //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:01:05.343 [0x1f7eb805ad0][21111984] //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp - file(s) up-to-date.
00004158 12:01:05.359 [0x1f7eb96a4c0] edit -c default //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:01:05.359 [0x1f7eb96a4c0][13001928] //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp#2 - opened for edit
00004158 12:01:05.475 [0x1f7eb115760] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:02:02.209 [0x1f7eb964b80] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil -c HVS_Game
00004158 12:02:02.298 [0x1f7eeb2d090] change -o
00004158 12:02:05.003 [0x1f7eeb2d090] reopen -c default -t utf8 //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:02:05.020 [0x1f7eeb2d090][15001942] //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp#2 - reopened; type utf8
00004158 12:02:05.090 [0x1f7eb115760] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:02:17.759 [0x1f7ee8505f0] change -o
00004158 12:02:17.912 [0x1f7eb113fc0] fstat -Olhp -Rco -e default //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:02:18.182 [0x1f7eb1147a0] fstat -m1 -Olhp -Rcu -e default //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:02:18.208 [0x1f7eb1147a0][21111977] //HVS_Game/... - no such file(s).
00004158 12:02:19.941 [0x1f7eec517f0] submit --parallel=0 -f submitunchanged -s -i
00004158 12:02:19.973 [0x1f7eec517f0][2204040e] Translation of file content failed near line 1 file C:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:02:19.973 [0x1f7eec517f0][30221c33] Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 124'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
00004158 12:02:26.997 [0x1f7eec95490] change -o
00004158 12:02:26.998 [0x1f7eec956b0] change -o 124
00004158 12:02:26.998 [0x1f7eec94390] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 12:02:26.998 [0x1f7eb96ebf0] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil
00004158 12:02:27.008 [0x1f7eb114200] fstat -Olhp //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:02:27.014 [0x1f7eb96e6a0] change -o
00004158 12:02:27.015 [0x1f7eb96f690] change -o 124
00004158 12:02:27.017 [0x1f7eb970ce0] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 12:02:27.022 [0x1f7eb113c60] fstat -Olhp -Rco -e 124 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:02:27.024 [0x1f7eb970020] change -o
00004158 12:02:27.069 [0x1f7eb114d40] fstat -m1 -Olhp -Rcu -e 124 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:02:27.070 [0x1f7eb114d40][21111977] //HVS_Game/... - no such file(s).
00004158 12:03:10.180 [0x1f7eb96d380] change -o 124
00004158 12:03:10.316 [0x1f7eb1150a0] fstat -Olhp -Rco -e 124 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:03:10.403 [0x1f7eb114d40] fstat -m1 -Olhp -Rcu -e 124 //HVS_Game/...
00004158 12:03:10.403 [0x1f7eb114d40][21111977] //HVS_Game/... - no such file(s).
00004158 12:03:12.786 [0x1f7eb8021d0] submit --parallel=0 -f submitunchanged -s -i
00004158 12:03:12.817 [0x1f7eb8021d0][2204040e] Translation of file content failed near line 1 file C:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp
00004158 12:03:12.817 [0x1f7eb8021d0][30221c33] Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 124'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
00004158 12:03:28.496 [0x1f7ee783920] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 12:03:28.512 [0x1f7ee78d990] changes -f -s pending -l -m 100 -u decil
00004158 12:03:28.512 [0x1f7ee78f970] depots
00004158 12:03:28.512 [0x1f7ee7921d0] stream -o -v //streamsDepot/mainline
00004158 12:03:28.524 [0x1f7eed610b0] dirs //depot/* //streamsDepot/* //streamsDepot/mainline/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/Missions/*
00004158 12:03:28.524 [0x1f7eb114680] fstat -Olhp -Dl -F ^headAction=delete & ^headAction=move/delete //depot/* //streamsDepot/* //streamsDepot/mainline/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Private/Missions/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/* //streamsDepot/mainline/Source/HVS/Public/Missions/*
00004158 12:03:28.546 [0x1f7eed61a40] change -o
00004158 12:03:28.546 [0x1f7eed611c0] client -o HVS_Game
00004158 12:03:28.546 [0x1f7eb114680][21111977] //depot/* - no such file(s).
00004158 12:03:28.546 [0x1f7eb114680][21111977] //streamsDepot/* - no such file(s).
00004158 12:03:28.594 [0x1f7eb114680] fstat -Olhp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_AttributeSet.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\WeaponSystemConstants.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSServer.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameInstance.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\GA_WeaponFire.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameMode.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_CheatManager.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_CharacterMovementComponent.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\p4ignore.txt c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_HUD.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameInstance.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\CaptureNode.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_LocalPlayer.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\AbilityTask_WeaponFire.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\GlobalStructs.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameState.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_Character.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_AttributeSet.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\HomeBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_CheatManager.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HeroDatabase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\AbilityTask_WeaponFire.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\ProjectileBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerController.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.uproject c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\README.md c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameState.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\CipherBeacon.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_LocalPlayer.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameMode.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Components\CharacterSoundsComponent.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerController.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\ProjectileBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.sln c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\HVS.Build.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_CharacterMovementComponent.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CaptureNode.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\Missions\BioWeaponContainer.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_HUD.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerState.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_GameSession.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerState.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\HomeBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSClient.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\GA_WeaponFire.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_Character.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\WeaponBase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVSEditor.Target.cs c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\HVS_PlayerStart.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HeroDatabase.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\WeaponBase.cpp c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_GameSession.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Public\HVS_PlayerStart.h c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\Source\HVS\Private\Missions\CipherBeacon.cpp
00004158 12:03:28.607 [0x1f7eb114680][21111977] c:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.sln - no such file(s).
```

Logs are completely useless, the file itself, is literally just a cpp text file, it's encoded with utf8, here is a photo of it in HxD. No bom. Why is it not working? Is there something I'm missing? Why is it only this file? Does perforce hate me?
[image: HxD]

Answer (score 2):

"Translation of file content failed" means that Perforce is trying to translate the file according to a Unicode character set that the file itself doesn't match.  The submit dialogue unfortunately doesn't show the Perforce filetype, but that should be visible in P4V's pending changelist tab next to the file, e.g. `<text>` or `<utf8>` or `<unicode>`.

For a UTF8 file with no BOM you probably want a filetype of either `text` or `utf8`; you can change this just by right-clicking the open file and saying "Change filetype".  If you've already got it set to `utf8`, try `utf8-bom` (I didn't look closely at your hex screenshot to verify that it's got no BOM, but it's an easy thing to try).  If neither UTF8 setting works for some reason, you can always make it `text` (to just treat it as ASCII, which is close enough to UTF8 that it'll generally work fine), or `binary` (to just preserve it byte-for-byte -- note that this disables line ending translation if the file is synced to other platforms).

Since this file is open for "edit", at least one previous revision was successfully submitted with the previous filetype, so it may be that you inadvertently changed the encoding of the file -- double-check your editor settings, since if your editor is set to change the encoding of every file you touch, this is likely to be a recurring annoyance!

Comment: Now that I'm squinting at your hex screenshot, that is not valid UTF8.  You're using a high-bit copyright symbol (`0xa9`); in UTF8 that'd be rendered with two bytes as `0xc2 0xa9`.  So your editor is set to save in some single-byte character set.  http://www.426.ch/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/ASCII-Table  If you don't want the file to be UTF8 I'd just reopen it as `text`, since Perforce's ASCII handling will basically just ignore the high characters.  But if you're sharing this file with other people that expect UTF8, fix your editor settings to match theirs!  :)

Comment: well if i save it as text, then the problem is that my compiler is thinking that it's "Mac" format and refuses to compile it

Comment: What if you save it as UTF8?  (Again -- the file you took the hex dump of is not UTF8, which is why the submit is failing.)

Comment: To be clear -- "save it as UTF-8" means *go into your editor and save a new version of the file to disk*, making sure this time that the character encoding is "utf-8".  After you do that, the hex for that (c) character should be `c2 a9` instead of just `a9`. 
 "Reopen it as text" means *go into Perforce and "change filetype"* -- this does not change the file on disk, but it changes the way that Perforce translates the file on submit.  The Perforce filetype just needs to match what's on disk, one way or another -- so if the Perforce filetype is `utf8`, the file on disk needs to be valid UTF-8.